# Which version of Ubuntu can I use on an iBook G4?

Tags: system-installation

I have a very old iBook G4 with a CPU speed of 1.33GHz and 256 MB memory.

It has a tiny little harddrive of 150GB partitioned into a 60GB and a 90GB at the moment. I want to replace the Mac OS on the 60GB partition with Ubuntu. The other partition only has documents on it.

Which versions of Ubuntu can I use?

Will I be able to access the other partition from Ubuntu or will I need to do something in the installation to tell Ubuntu it is there?

I didn't partition the hard drive myself and I don't know so much about this kind of setup. I can get rid of the partition if it will be easier.

I only have a fairly basic computer literacy, I hope I am explaining myself well!

Answer (score 1):

That laptop has an old PowerPC CPU. Lubuntu (a very lightweight version of Ubuntu) still offers PowerPC downloads, but requires a minimum of 640MB of RAM for the PowerPC versions. You can try the "alternate" installer, but with such little RAM, it might not be usable *if* it even runs.

You can download **lubuntu-16.04-alternate-powerpc.iso** from the following site:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/xenial/release/

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice, perhaps I will have to abandon the idea. I appreciate your frank and clear advice.

Answer (score 0):

For an old G4 you're only hope could be Lubuntu (any version). It's not about the version number (14, 15, 16, etc), it's more about the *flavor*. And the lightest flavor of Ubuntu is Lubuntu. And that still might be too much for the G4. Maybe try a micro-linux (like Puppy, Slax or Damn Small Linux). Look for any linux with an ultra-lite desktop environment (enlightenment, openbox, icewm).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it seems like it will stress such an old computer to have a new OS, maybe I will have to abandon the idea. Then again, I don't really use it so it would be no great loss if it didn't work anymore. I will certainly look into the micro versions you have listed. Thanks again.